# Laravel 5.2 module routes not working

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am fresher in `Laravel`.I created a module his project,followed [this tutorial](http://kamranahmed.info/blog/2015/12/03/creating-a-modular-application-in-laravel/)

Now I am facing a problem,how to hit the module controller into URL?

Actually I am not sure that module name should be mentioned into URL or not .

Answer (score 0):

You can use Controller actions as urls by using the following in your routes.php file.

`Route::get('module-name', 'ModuleController@action');`

Check out the below for more information on Laravel Routing :)

https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing

Comment: I am getting error:-Class ContactsController does not exist. ContactsController is controller which I created

Comment: Class ContactsController does not exist.

Comment: Couple of things to check. Just double check that the file actually exists - I've done this a couple of times. Also - check that all of the PHP in the ContactsController is valid. 

If, for example, you have missed off a PHP closing tag, the error it will give you will be either `unexpected end of input` or it will say it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I Resolved this problem using:-

```
 Route::group(['namespace' => 'App\Modules\ModuleName\Controllers'],function(){ 

    Route::get('module-name', ['as' => 'action', 'uses' => 'ModuleController@action']);
});
```

Now it's working properly.

Comment: You can shorten this down to `Route::get('module-name', 'App\Modules\ModuleName\Controller\ModuleController@action')`